# AWS CLI tool not able to launch t1.micro instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

```
aws ec2 run-instances --region us-west-2 --image-id ami-d732f0b7 --count 1 --instance-type t1.micro --security-groups launch-wizard-1 --key-name key-name
```

The error returned is:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type.
```

However, from web console I am able to launch a t1.micro instance using the same ubuntu image (provided in us-west-2 region)

Comment: Are you sure? `t1.micro` is greyed out for me for the same AMI in `us-west-2`

Comment: @helloV http://s13.postimg.org/824mrd8fb/lol.png

Comment: The image shows `t2.micro` (current gen), but in the CLI, you are passing `t1.micro` (previous gen)

Answer (score 2):

as @helloV mentioned the `t1.micro` is disabled. You can check details on this particular ami :

```
aws> ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-d732f0b7 --region us-west-2
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
            "Name": "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20160714",
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
            "ImageId": "ami-d732f0b7",
            "State": "available",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-47713105",
                        "VolumeSize": 8,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2",
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb",
                    "VirtualName": "ephemeral0"
                },
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sdc",
                    "VirtualName": "ephemeral1"
                }
            ],
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "ImageLocation": "099720109477/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20160714",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "OwnerId": "099720109477",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "CreationDate": "2016-07-15T10:37:25.000Z",
            "Public": true,
            "ImageType": "machine"
        }
    ]
}
```

The key is `"VirtualizationType": "hvm"` so this ami supports only *hardware virtual machine (HVM)* virtualization type.

t1 (and other 1st generation AMI) instances support *paravirtual (PV)* virtualization.

You can read more about the differences in the [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html)